# understand child scope angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i try understand scope angular.I see the docs write
childScope.aString = 'child string'
The prototype chain is not consulted, and a new aString property is added to the childScope. This new property hides/shadows the parentScope property with the same name. This will become very important when we discuss ng-repeat and ng-include below.

[image]

childScope.anArray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryxGI.png) = 22
childScope.anObject.property1 = 'child prop1'
The prototype chain is consulted because the objects (anArray and anObject) are not found in the childScope. The objects are found in the parentScope, and the property values are updated on the original objects. No new properties are added to the childScope; no new objects are created. (Note that in JavaScript arrays and functions are also objects.)
[image]

I dont't understand a string NOT IS CONSULTED BY PROTOTYPE but Object Is done!